# Jquery Incompatibilities

Tags: jquery, css, menu, accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion menu with css and jquery, the css works fine but i can seem to make my js work, can anyone check for errors?

here is the css:

```
#wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.accordionButton {  
width: 800px;
float: left;
background: #003366;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-menu { 
width: 800px;
float: left;
background: #95B1CE;
display: none;
}
```

The Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/********************************************************************************************************************
SIMPLE ACCORDIAN STYLE MENU FUNCTION
********************************************************************************************************************/   
$('class.accordionButton').click(function() {
    $('class.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');  
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
});

/********************************************************************************************************************
CLOSES ALL DIVS ON PAGE LOAD
********************************************************************************************************************/   
$("class.sub-menu").hide();

});
```

This is made in a wordpress and i'm using the  code to get my menu, here is the [link](https://www.essr.net/cdcomunicacao/al5580/PAA/#) to the site.

The menu is the one on the left side the first link

Comment: You are loading the jquery library as http content in https web site. due to which it is getting blocked.check the console.

Comment: What is `class` (in `class.sub-menu` and `class.accordionButton`)? Do you have a `class` element? Read about selectors a bit... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: at first i was trying with a div so it had to be $('div.accordionButton'), same for a class no? i'm not very experient with js

Comment: It is not JavaScript, it is a CSS selector. `class.sub-menu` refers to `<class class="sub-menu">`.

Comment: omg... ok i think i made it right, like this? $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
  $('div.sub-menu').slideUp();  
  $(this).next().slideDown();
 });
 
 $("div.sub-menu").hide();

});

Comment: First, try and then ask. ;)

Comment: i did, but it still doesn't work nothing

Comment: @Angus Probably because you don't have an element `<div class="accordionButton">`.

Comment: i've gone over that and fixed it